# std::get returns error while working with vector of tuples

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdtuple

I'm trying to create a vector that holds tuples

**this is my code:**

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,int,int>>> vec;
...
...
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    vec.push_back(std::tuple<std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,int,int>>());
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
        std::get<0>(vec[i]).push_back(std::tuple<std::string,int,int>());
        std::get<0>(std::get<0>(vec[i]))[j] = value; //error
        std::get<1>(std::get<0>(vec[i]))[j] = value1;
    }
```

Error:

```
no matching function for call to 'get(std::vector<std::tuple<std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int> >&)'*
```

What is wrong with it?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you intend to create a vector-of-tuple-of-vector-of-tuple-of-string,int,int? If so, I would STRONGLY recommend revisiting your design, as an object may be better suited to your task. (Also, if that is what you wanted, you have two missing `>` at the end.

Comment: From the error message, you're trying to pass `get` a vector. `get` only works for tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the working version of your code

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,int,int>>>> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    vec.push_back(std::tuple<std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,int,int>>>());
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
        std::get<0>(vec[i]).push_back(std::tuple<std::string,int,int>());
        std::get<0>(std::get<0>(vec[i])[j]) = "str";
        std::get<1>(std::get<0>(vec[i])[j]) = 1;
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cdc4531904a56b3

You have a few missing `>` and the you completely messed up the assignment statement.

My suggestion: DO NOT ever create data structure like this. If you need complex data structure, make real structs/classes. Give them meaningful name. This will make the code much more readable and maintainable.

e.g.

```
struct Record {
    std::string name;
    int value;
    int otherValue;
};
```

instead of

```
std::tuple<std::string,int,int>
```

Also you have a tuple contains only single element, which doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: I was about to answer, but you nailed it. If the OP wanted to create a vector of tuples ONLY, then the declaration should be `std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,int,int>>`.

Comment: You are right, I was looking for better design, didn't thought of old structs.